What is the type or name of this oscillator circuit?
I am trying to simulate a circuit for an eddy current gap sensor.
It is made of two inverters to get 360 degree phase.
It should give different frequencies of oscillation based on the inductor value L1.
I modeled the circuit and it did not work.
I want to know the type of name of this oscillator circuit.

I got the circuit from this paper on low cost eddy current sensors.
From what I have searched online, 74LVC is low voltage CMOS and is used for low power, high switching speed applications.
74HC04 is high voltage CMOS inverter and is used for low switching speed application. The data sheet of SN74LVC2G04 does not mention that there is a buffer stage after the inverter that makes this unsuitable for oscillator application. The data sheet of SN74HC04 mentions that the inputs are buffered.
What property do I look for when chosing the inverter for this application?
I tried simulating the circuit given in the answer by D.A.S below and the circuit oscillates fine. The Clamping using Schotky diodes is necessary. The oscillation frequency is 250 kHz for 90uH and goes upto 740 kHz for 10uH inductance. One thing that is not clear is why two different Schotky diodes 1N5711 and 1N5712 are used for clamping the inductor voltage before giving to the inverter.



a dead osc.?... Wouldn't you rather know why it doesn't work or how to fix it?

U1 is only biasing U2. It is not providing any phase shift. U2 is the only inverter in the oscillator loop. Where did you get this circuit from?

The schematic is wrong (as well as difficult to read). U1 doesn't do anything as you have the inputs and outputs mixed up. C1 and the resistor should go to the input of the inverter. The output of U1 should go to the input of U2.  Buffered devices such as you have chosen usually do not work in this type of circuit. You probably need an unbuffered inverter such as the 74HCU04.

I think you want to use two quadrature sine waves for Eddy Current if you want to measure complex impedance.  I shipped one that had an incremental sensitivity of 10 ppm in vector impedance with PLL's 100 kHz,  200 kHz but I would use 100 kHz, 1 MHz today.

Where do the diode designations (1N5711/2) come from?

The diodes shown in the answer are the input protection diodes, they are intrinsic to the logic gate -- the Falstad simulator I believe needs to express them as individual parts, the real IC however already contains them. They are not important to the circuit in normal operation. || What initial conditions did you use in the simulation? That's a pretty tremendous startup transient.

@greybeard, the diode designations are from the Falstad simulation model posted in the answer below.

@TimWilliams I have set the initial voltage at the inductor node to 1V to start the oscillations using .ic V(LCRsignal)=1 in the simulation.

Strange, it seems I(L1) has been set to around 1 as well. Setting L1 IC to something more reasonable, or zero, should seem to do.

Some errors


R3 is too high to get the Q you need to overcome losses.
R3 <= 1 Ohm is ideal
IF > 1 then Q is too low.
Even 0 Ohms is OK, if L can handle 30 mA loop current.

- It's an LC tank oscillator with positive feedback. It needs high-impedance loading, and current limiting.

C1 is too big causing long delays to bias the input to Vdd/2= 100 ms delay to startup. I added series with C1 >= 10 K to the current limit on ESD diodes.

C1 = 10pF to 100 pF to speed up bias time and start oscillating.

R2 can be anything > = 1 M to 33 M

U1 to U2 is miswired.

0 < R3 < 1 ohm.

I added 10k series to allow the ESD clamp diodes to work if the R3(sens) = 0 Ohms then it is possible to get more than 3.3Vpp.

Rout = 22 to 33 ohms nom. is the internal Vol/Io specs for the 74LVC2G04  ( as I recall +/- 50%)




My Sim Adjust L with thumbwheel.
Parasitic ESL can cause spurious resonance on 74LVC04 and snubber may be necessary but this has > 50% lower impedance (22~33 Ohms) than the 74HC series (~ 50 Ohms). So beware of long traces in the feedback loops.
Ensure 0.01 to 0.1 uF decoupling is used very near IC. You can use the Hex version inverters too.
